# Insert the Name of a BindingSource into a String?

Tags: xaml, binding, datatemplate, datatrigger, tabitem

I want to use a DataTemplate to change the Header of some TabItems.
So far I have this Code, which works fine:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"  x:Class="SFgame.MainWindow"
        Title="SoccerFusion" Height="600" Width="1000" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Grid>
        <TabControl TabStripPlacement="Bottom">
            <TabControl.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabPanel}">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                </Style>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="mmHeaderTemplate">
                    <Image Name="mmItem1" />
                    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="mmItem1" Property="Source" Value="data\Images\Menu\ActiveItem.png" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="mmItem1" Property="Source" Value="data\Images\Menu\InactiveItem.png" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.Resources>
            <TabItem Height="32" Width="32" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource mmHeaderTemplate}" IsSelected="True">
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Height="32" Width="32" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource mmHeaderTemplate}" >
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Height="32" Width="32" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource mmHeaderTemplate}" >
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Height="32" Width="32" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource mmHeaderTemplate}" >
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The only problem is, that now all TabItem-Headers have the same Picture. All TabItems should have different pairs of Pictures fpr active and inactive.

So I guess I would pass the path of the picture as parameter, but I just can't figure out how that works.

The only thing I can find is: "Can't pass Parameters".

If that really doesn't work. Is there an alternative? For example give the TabItem a Name like "TabItem1" and usw the Path "data\Images\Menu\Tabitem1_active.png" and "data\Images\Menu\Tabitem1_inactive.png" as Source? Can I insert the Name of the Binding-Source into a string?

Edit: 
I'm a little closer to a solution

```
<Setter TargetName="mmItem1" Property="Source">
    <Setter.Value>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}{1}{2}">
            <Binding Mode="OneTime" Source="data\Images\Menu\" />
            <Binding Mode="OneTime" Source="??????" />
            <Binding Mode="OneTime" Source="inactive.png" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

with this code instead of the one on the upper, i can concat three strings. the only thing i need now, is the name of the sourcecontrol/bindingsource

Next Edit:
I'm a little closer i think. I succeeded in getting a string from my tabitem to the Template, by using the Header of the TabItem.

Code looks like this now:

```
<Page
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="SoccerFusion" Height="400" Width="400">
  <Grid>
    <TabControl TabStripPlacement="Bottom">
        <TabControl.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabPanel}">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            </Style>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="mmHeaderTemplate">
              <Grid>
                <Image Name="mmImg" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content, StringFormat='{}{0}'}" />
              </Grid>
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Value="True">
                    ????? HERE COMES THE PROBLEM ??????
                        <Setter TargetName="mmImg" Property="Source" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content, StringFormat='{}{0}active.png'}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Value="False">
                    ????? HERE COMES THE PROBLEM ??????
                        <Setter TargetName="mmImg" Property="Source" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content, StringFormat='{}{0}inactive.png'}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.Resources> 
        <TabItem Height="32" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource mmHeaderTemplate}" IsSelected="True" Header="mmItem1">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Height="32" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource mmHeaderTemplate}" Header="mmItem2" >
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Height="32" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource mmHeaderTemplate}" Header="mmItem3" >
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Height="32" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource mmHeaderTemplate}" Header="mmItem4" >
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
  </Grid>
</Page>
```

The Problem is: 
I generate a String and give it to the Image as a Source. Which works fine.
But the Source needs an URI and can't do anything with the String

Any Ideas?